# pick the right relationship - Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

I need to make users to follow (just like in twitter) other users in my app.

So by this user(1) that follows user(2) can read view his posts- but not vice versa.

what's the relationship for it? is it many to many ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the many-to-many relation with pivot table I guess.

Comment: You sure I shouldn't use has many thorugh?

Since I am accessing other user's posts?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it really looks like you should use many-to-many relation with pivot table in this case.

Comment: I will do use many-to-many since Martin Bean suggested the same. Thank you.

Comment: By the way - I already have users and posts tables. So now I need to create the pivot table, that would be called something like: followee_user_posts.

And this is where I migrate the migration Martin Bean mentioned above. So far so good?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a many-to-many: many users can follow many other users. So your schema would look something like this:

```php
$table->integer('follower_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('followee_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('followee_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: thanks. Should I also add a model for the followee posts?